# Sharepoint page, remove auto generated HTML line to pass WCAG Web standard

Tags: sharepoint, accessibility, wcag

We are trying to achieve WCAG Web standard on our website, but an error is coming on the below HTML code.I would like to remove the below code but this is autogenerated by Sharepoint. HOw can I resolve this problem?

```
<div style="display:none" id="imgPrefetch">
<img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23">
<img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23">
<img src="/PublishingImages/logo.png?rev=23">
</div>
```

Comment: The error is because there is no alt attribute on the img elements. I don't know how to remove the sharepoint generated code, but that might be of use.

Comment: Thanx @TheWaxMann, yeah there should be an alt attribute. i raised a ticket to Microsoft already a week back and there is still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given actually is WCAG2.0 compliant. This is an issue with a bad validator, not bad source code.

Elements with [`display:none` should be hidden to screen readers and text-based browsers, as well as regular visual browsers](http://juicystudio.com/article/screen-readers-display-none.php), so regardless of the content the `img` elements should not be rendered under standard conditions.

Remember, in **WCAG the G stands for "Guidelines"**, and should be treated as such, and not as hard and fast rules. If the content won't be rendered by any browser, then by definition it can't be non-compliant.